# ¿Cómo copiar código de sublime text 3 como RTF?

Tags: sublimetext3, rtf

He revisado los menús que tiene pero en ninguno aparece copiar como RTF, solamente aparece la opción clásica de copiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instala el paquete de SublimeHighlight, con el Package Control (Ctrl+Shift+P) Install Package buscando: Highlight

Si todo va bien cuando selecciones código en el menú contextual te debe aparecer Copy as HTML/RTF

Repo de referencia: https://github.com/n1k0/SublimeHighlight